# Im creating a program that generates a palette from a true color image, need help with some file formats

Tags: image, file-format

Im creating a program that generates a palette from a true color image, I need some help with some file formats

It already creates a photoshop cs3 palette

i haven't found any info on how to make a Paintshop pro 8 palette or a gimp palette

plus i would be happy to look up any other art program palette types to improve compatibility with my program

Answer (score 3):

GIMP palettes are just text files. Assuming you're pulling RGB values, you generate a text file like this:

```
GIMP Palette
Name: custompalette
Columns: 4
#
  0   0   0     Index 3
 65  38  30     Index 4
103  62  49     Index 6
 79  73  72     Index 7
114 101  97     Index 8
208 127 100     Index 9 
151 144 142     Index 10
221 207 199     Index 11
```

Comment: Just a note: the first line here should be "index 0" up "index 7" and will be index 0 if openned in GIMP. Pillow, the "Python Imageing Library" project has a broken behavior up to version 9.2 which increases the index of colors on each line, even if it is a header or a comment line and that is likely the source of the incorrectt numbers here.. As this is a round world, _this_ sample ended up in Pillow's tests and reinforced the broken behavior it currentlyhas. Check https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/6639

Answer (score 0):

For PSP palettes: [.pal file extension](http://www.cryer.co.uk/filetypes/p/pal.htm)

According to [the GIMP's documentation](http://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-concepts-palettes.html), the `.gpl` file format is in ASCII so it shouldn't be difficult to create a convertor by looking at the file itself.

Answer (score 0):

Paint.NET palettes are easy. It's a .txt with each line being a hex-color (AARRGGBB). Semicolons (;) are comments.
Example:

```
;comment
FF000000
FFFFFFFF
00000000
```

GIMP uses an ASCII plaintext format with extension .gpl. Take a peek with your favorite notepad program.